# Maya expression changing frame range problems

Tags: expression, maya, mel

I added an attribute to a control curve that changes the start frame of multiple groups. This is the expression that I come up with that I put in the expression editor.

```
$basename = "R_M_TM_Step_01_ctrl";
string $selected[] = `ls -sl -sn` ;
string $result = substituteAllString($selected[0], $basename , "");
string $addName = ($basename + $result);
if ($selected[0] == $addName )
{
    if ($selected[0] == $addName )
        {
        int $tyme=`getAttr $selected.StartFrame`;
        SelectHierarchy;
        copyKey -time ":"  ;
        cutKey -time ":"  ;
        pasteKey -time $tyme;
        select $selected;

        }
   if ($selected[0] == $addName )
        {
        int $tyme=`getAttr $selected.StartFrame`;
        SelectHierarchy;
        copyKey -time ":"  ;
        cutKey -time ":"  ;
        pasteKey -time $tyme;
        select $selected;

        }
        }
```

The problem is that I need to import this control and groups multiple times. I need some way to query the select control curve (R_M_TM_Step_01_ctrl) even when it imported (new name R_M_TM_Step_01_ctrl1, R_M_TM_Step_01_ctrl2, and so on). For the most part this script works but is there a better to move all those keys. Or is there an expression evaluates only under that particular control curve.

Also I need a command change evaluation. If I have a evaluation set to "always" then it runs the expression every frame. I thought that "demand" would work but it doesn't. I think I need some kind of "if statement". Can you guys help?

Comment: I highly suggest that you change this from an expression to a script that runs in a custom shelf. That way you don't have the problem of it executing every frame and it won't effect parallel evaluation since it'll detect an expression in the scene.

Comment: Thanks Green Cell, You helped me to figured it out. I added an enum attribute that I could turn on and off, to make a window that pops up so the user can change the start frame.